# How does Lua's floating-point handling differ from other languages?

Tags: floating-point, lua, floating-accuracy

When I execute `0.1 + 0.2` in Lua, I get `0.3` exactly. If I do the same in Ruby or Python for example, I get `0.30000000000000004`. I understand floating-point rounding errors, but why doesn't this problem occur in Lua? What does Lua do differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0.1+0.2` is not `0.3` exactly. Try this code:

```
print((0.1+0.2)==0.3)
print(string.format("%.17g",0.1+0.2))
```

I assume you're using `print` or `io.write` to print those values. In this case, Lua is just not printing all digits. Internally, Lua uses full-length, native floating-point representation. The technical explanation is that `print` and `io.write` format numbers using the format in `LUA_NUMBER_FMT` defined in `luaconf.h`, which by default is `"%.14g"`.

Comment: BTW, why this parameter is not "%.16g" (so all integers which can be exactly stored in double would display correctly)?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I was asking about `LUA_NUMBER_FMT` value defined in `luaconf.h` without respect to this SO question.  Why it was chosen to be "%.14g"?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Ah, I see.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, "%.14g" was chosen exactly to avoid noise such as `0.30000000000000004` for simple applications.