# Lua number comparison returns wrong result

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I tried to use the hamerspoon package to write a timer as follows.

```lua
  local function startTimer()
    local totalSeconds = 5
    local i = 0
    local function onTimeout()
      i = i + .1
      local stopTimer = i == totalSeconds -- THIS BOOLEAN COMPARISSON RETURNS WRONG RESULT
      print('stopTimer:', stopTimer)
      print(i, totalSeconds, type(i), type(totalSeconds), 5 == 5.0)
      if stopTimer then 
        timer:stop()
      end
    end
    local timer = hs.timer.new(.1, onTimeout)
    timer:start()
  end
```

As you can see in the output below

- `stopTimer` variable in above function is always `false` even for a comparisson of `5 == 5.0`
- The types of both variables are numbers
- Simply printing `5 == 5.0` seems to show the correct result

[image]

`stopTimer` variable should be `false` when `i` is `5`

Comment: Replace `i = i + .1` with `i = math.floor((i + .1) * 10 + 0.5) / 10`

Comment: 0.1 does not have an exact binary representation.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/18005146/107090

Comment: One small thing I'd add to "floats are imprecise": They *appear* precise because `tostring` covertly rounds them by default. Lua printing `5.0` is wrong; in reality the number won't be exactly `5.0`. Otherwise a duplicate. As for the fix: Just use tenths instead, then everything can keep being exact integers. That is, do `i = i + 1`, then compare `i*10 == totalSeconds` (similarly, you could also use milliseconds, nanoseconds, attoseconds etc. if you need even more precision).